# xlwings error using caller from excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am trying to call python code from excel using

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
```

If file path is in English, it works. However, if the path has other language, it raise below Error popup

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py:2692: UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

  throw = (os.path.normpath(os.path.realpath(impl.fullname.lower())) != os.path.normpath(fullname.lower()))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "test.py", line 13, in plot_chart

    wb = xw.Book.caller()

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 545, in caller

    return cls(impl=app.books.open(fullname).impl)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 2695, in open

    "Cannot open two workbooks named '%s', even if they are saved in different locations." % name

ValueError: Cannot open two workbooks named 'test.xlsm', even if they are saved in different locations.
```

Guess this has something to do with unicode problem. I did not have this kind of problem with previous version. (e.g. 0.6 or 0.7) This is new problem after I updated to version 0.9.2.

Thank you for any help

p.s. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Yes, we are aware of that and there's already an issue open for that: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/546

Comment: @FelixZumstein Thank you quick update. Wonder when 0.9.3 will be available on Anaconda package

Comment: You can always use pip to upgrade even if you have it installed via conda before.

Comment: @FelixZumstein I did not know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

xlwings version 0.9.3 solve above problem. Self closing the question.